# How to change the order of categorical values on y axis of a plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I just wanted to change the the order of the categorical values in the y axis in this plot:

[image: Current plot]

I want the following order:

```
yax = ['empty',
       '1 to 2 range',
       '3 to 5 range',
       '6+ range',
       '1 person',
       '2 people',
       '3 people',
       '4 people',
       '5 people',
       '6 people',
       '7 people',
       '8 people',
       '9 people',
       '10 people']
```

My code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11,6))
plt.plot(df.index.time, df['status'], marker='.', lw=0, ms=10, color = 'darkgreen')
plt.xlim(["00:00:00", "23:59:59"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, and if possible, embed any images rather than provide a link to an external image hosting service.

Comment: Appologies, I'm new here and new to python. I've added my code

Comment: No need to apologise. :) And welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks! Was my question clear enough?

Comment: Yep, certainly clear enough. It might help people to answer if you can create an MVC example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - which would mean including some toy example data. When writing an answer I (and many others) like to be able to run some code to make sure I'm right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a categorical column, and then sorting by this column, e.g.:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2],'a':['high','low','middle']})

df['cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'], ['low', 'middle', 'high'])

df=df.sort_values(by='cat') ## try with and without this line

plt.figure(figsize=(11,6))
plt.plot(df['x'], df['a'].values, marker='.', lw=0, ms=10, color = 'darkgreen')

plt.show()
```